# Женский вариант "басилевс"

Tags: словообразование

Возникла необходимость образовать женскую форму от титула басилевс. Не найдя никаких источников на эту тему в Интернете, я пришёл к варианту «басилевсида». Приемлемо ли?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Базилевс**(басиле́вс; также басиле́й, василе́вс)
(гр. *basileus — букв, скипетродержатель*)
1) у древних греков глава племени, союза племен, военачальник племени, верховный судья и верховный жрец.
2) обычный эпитет, используемый в Др. Греции для характеристики царей;
3) один из титулов спартанских царей;
4) в Афинах титул второго архонта — архонт-Базилевс;
5) официальный титул византийского императора.
([**Большой юридический словарь. Академик.ру. 2010**](http://jurisprudence.academic.ru/7766/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81))

**Базилисса** - жена базилевса (правителя) или правительница.

*Спустя несколько лет на голову Феодоры поднялась диадема **базилисс**, она была коронована вместе с Юстинианом в храме св. Софии.*

*Явление Феодоры в тюрьме показалось узникам сошествием ангела. **Базилисса** медлила.

– Привет тебе, Иптиос, – наконец сказала она.*

*Подобно многим обитателям Палатия, редко покидавшим его пределы, **базилисса** Анна Комнина понятия не имела, чем живет и дышит раскинувшийся за стенами дворца огромный Константинополь.*

[Васили́сса, или Васили́са (др.-греч. Βασίλισσα) — женское русское имя греческого происхождения; восходит к др.-греч. βασίλισσα, βασίλιννα ("василисса", "василинна") — жена василевса, правителя; царица.
(*Базилисса, басилисса* — в Византии первая буква имени стала произносится как **В** и в славянский язык имя дошло уже как *Василиса*.  Церковная форма имени — *Васили́сса*.)]